# How to get data in one combo at the SelectionChanged event of other combo in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My application is in Silverlight(c#.Net)

I have a form with three combo boxes,Country,State,City.

My requirement is I want to populate my State Combo box at the Selectionchanged Event of Country combo box.

When the user select some country than the State of that Country should be populated in State combo.

Database Tables:

- Country Table-(CountryID,CountryName)
- State Table-(StateID,StateName,CountryId)
- City Table-(CityID,CityName,StateId)

To retrieve value from Database im coding in Service.svc.cs File

This is my Code. This code will get Country Record.

```
    public class GetCountry
            {
                public string CountryName { get; set; }
            }

     [OperationContract]
            public List<GetCountry> GetCountryRecord()
            {
                using (Entities context = new Entities())
                {
                    return (from c in context.CountryMasters
                            select new GetCountry
                            {
                                CountryName = c.CountryName,
                            }).ToList<GetCountry>();
                }
            }

  //Code to Get State from State_Master table


  public class GetState
    {
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }



   [OperationContract]
    public List<GetState> GetStateRecord(int countryId)
    {
        using (Entities context = new Entities())
        {
            return (from c in context.StateMasters
                    select new GetState 
                    {
                        StateName = c.StateName,
                    }).ToList<GetState>();
        }
    }
   //End of State Code
```

This is my code in Form.xaml.cs. It will populate countries in Country combo box

```
     client = new ServiceReference1.AlumniServiceClient();
      client.GetCountryRecordCompleted += (s, ea) =>
                    {
                        cboCountry.ItemsSource = ea.Result.Select(b => b.CountryName).ToList();
                    };
                client.GetCountryRecordAsync();
```

Please Suggest me Changes in the  query in my Service.svc.cs file to get my required result or any other way to get it.

```
    return (**from c in context.StateMasters
                            select new GetState**
```

This is my code in Form.xaml.cs at selectionChanged Event of Country Combobox

```
    private void cboCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var client = new ServiceReference1.AlumniServiceClient();

                client.GetStateRecordCompleted += (s, ea) =>
                {
                    cboState.ItemsSource = ea.Result.Select(b => b.StateName).ToList();                     };
                client.GetStateRecordAsync();
            }
```

But this will get me All the States present in the StatesMaster

Comment: you have the CountryID in your State table, why don't you send the CountryID of the selected country to the web service and filter on the server?!

Comment: Please do not keep asking the same question over and over. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your direct question but I believe its a better solution to what you are trying to achieve
Let your Country data construct on the client side have a property of `ObservableCollection<State>`, then bind the State `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` to the `SelectedItem.States` of the Countries `ComboBox` (using ElementName binding), then you don't need to worry about `SelectionChanged` events etc. The same will apply to State & City relationship.
As a non-US citizen I feel obliged to remind you that most other Countries do not have 'States' :)

Comment: For your future reference, when you see a "possible duplicate of" in the comments it will be because a vote has been cast to close the question.   Follow the link provided and add your answer to the linked question instead.  That will allow daft duplicates to be closed and in this case hopefully deleted whilst not losing any answers.

Comment: Thanks, have re-posted answer

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your direct question but I believe its a better solution to what you are trying to achieve
Let your Country data construct on the client side have a property of `ObservableCollection<State>`, then bind the State ComboBox's `ItemsSource` to the `SelectedItem.States` of the Countries ComboBox (using `ElementName` binding), then you don't need to worry about `SelectionChanged` events etc. The same will apply to State & City relationship.
As a non-US citizen I feel obliged to remind you that most other Countries do not have 'States' :)